# android email address getting and storing and displaying

Tags: android, email, contactscontract

I am new to android. So I request you to be patient with me. I am trying to write an application where on pressing a button the contacts API is opened. Then the user chooses the contact. Then I want to get the chosen contact in `onAcitvityResult(int reqcode, int rescode, Intent data)`. Is there a way to do this without getting the Uri and querying for it through the whole database?
This is my code where the second activity starts:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

      Log.d(TAG, "contact button clicked");
      Toast.makeText(ctx, "Contact button clicked",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      Intent contacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
      contacts.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

      startActivityForResult(contacts,1);
}
```

Am I correct in using `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` and `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`?

Is the intent I am using correct? 
I get the feeling that I should include email specifics here.

And this is where I deal with the result from activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String email=""; long id;
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            // get the contact ID
            Uri contacturi= data.getData();
            Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(contacturi,null,null,null,null);
            id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            c.close();

            // get the data package containing the email address for the contact
            c=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{Email.DATA1}, 
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + Email.MIMETYPE + "=?",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(id), Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}, null);

            email=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA1));
            Log.d(TAG, "email is" + email);
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "requestCode is not 1");
    }

    EditText ctext= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contacttxt);
    ctext.append(email);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() ends");
}
```

I am getting a runtime exception saying that `failure delivering result`.
Should I include some `setResult()` method??
Thank you in advance.

Comment: code examples would be great.

Comment: should i be using broadcast receiver? will that make any difference? any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to debug and pinpointed the problem. It is in this line: 
id=c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

Comment: I figured out the error. The error is that c.getDouble(....) does not work. Instead make id int and dont use the c.getdouble() method. I am getting an id(13), when I run the program. Similar problem occurred with email=c.getString(); I dont know why. BTW I dont know if me ignoring the c.getDouble() gives me the actual id.

Comment: it'd be very much appreciated if one could tell me why the getDouble() or the getString() is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it :)
You have to add c.moveToFirst(); two times, after the two initializations as the 2 cursors.
But I am not getting why. Could anyone explain it?